# Evenly distribute components relatively their size

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

Say there is `HGroup` which is 100px wide, and there are two images within: `image_1` is 20px and `image_2` is 30px.

I want `image_1` to be centered within first 40 pixels (from pixel 11 to 30) and `image_2` within remaining 60 pixels (from pixel 56 to 85) since they divide the whole 100-pixels wide space relatively their size.

Is there a component or property within Spark which allow to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but there isn't any method to do this. The instances names  have been created for the example:

```
// container width = 100
var C:HGroupContainer = new HGroupContainer();
this.addChild(C);

const W1:int = 40;
const W2:int = 60;

var r1:Rect1 = new Rect1();
r1.x = (W1 - r1.width) / 2;
this.addChild(r1);

var r2:Rect2 = new Rect2();
r2.x =  W1 + (W2 - r2.width) / 2; 
this.addChild(r2);
```

The coordinates x = 0, y = 0 corresponding to the upper-left corner of the images.

Comment: That's not going to work in Flex using layout containers. That's simply not how the layout engine works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the images in HGroups and set the horizontal alignment to center there. That's the Flex way to do it.

Comment: How can I make them occupy relative space? Everything I do just makes them glue to each other and attach to left side of a window (in case horizontalAlignment not specified, or to center of a window if it's "center"). Space between two pictures appear only when I specify **gap** but it's fixed - doesn't change when window size changes.

Comment: The groups surrounding them have to take care of that. You could set the size for example when the images are loaded: image with + paddings.

Comment: Well, making dynamic changes to the components composition will surely handle the problem (at least reimplementing the "measure()" function). But I would like to know how it is possible to do specifying all components statically as part of MXML structure.

Comment: That's even easier. Just set the widths of the components explicitly in MXML with all the other properties and styles.

Comment: It is not possible to know the widths of all the images in sum (or even separately) since they aren't even loaded at MXML specification part. Hm ..

Comment: But then that's the part to calculate. I'll try to provide an example later.

Comment: Well, programmatically it is surely possible - the answer is then "no, there are no components or properties which allow to do that". But not sure yet ...